# Websocket library for browsers?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, websocket

Are there websocket libraries (like ajax for jquery) I can use on the browsers with fallback to ajax long polling?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Library with WebSockets support and fallback long polling solution would probably depend also on server side technology and not only browser client. Try to look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for example.

Comment: Socket IO is great but it's important to understand that it is an implementation layer on top of WebSockets (with fall backs to other mechanisms). It is not "WebSockets library" exactly but a framework that uses WebSockets (among other things) for client-server communication.

Answer (score 23):

I found that Socket.IO implements a weird, arbitrary layer over the WebSocket protocol. I'd rather just pass raw data back and forth, so for my project, I went with [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js).

web-socket-js works similarly to Socket.IO in that it reverts to using Flash sockets if WebSocket support is unavailable. Thus, it works in all the major browsers that support Flash (I tested this myself).

Just make sure you open port 843 in your firewall or you'll get a Flash security policy error. You'll probably need a script to listen on port 843 as well...I used em-websocket for the socket server, and in its readme I believe is a link to a Perl script that provides this.

Comment: I found the following link helpful with regards to hosting the policy script - http://briangonzalez.org/posts/websockets-polyfill

Answer (score 6):

I have been using SignalR for the last several months, and it is awesome. It does what Socket.IO does, but maybe even better. It degrades as follows: Web Sockets, Server Sent Events, Forever Frame, AJAX long polling. Only works with .NET though.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need server support for that as well. Kaazing WebSocket Gateway supports a very fast emulation/Polyfill. If you have a plugin like Flash it may use that (opportunistic optimization), but if you don't it emulates WebSocket with encrypted streaming, which is a lot more efficient than long polling. It comes with SSE and Cross Document Messaging support and emulation as well, as well as many higher level protocol abstractions (JMS/Stomp, XMPP, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Union Server has WebSocket support with fallback to comet-style AJAX communication. Union is a platform for creating connected applications, such as online multiplayer games.

http://www.unionplatform.com